# Invoking a list of functions. How to get their return values and use parameter that could be part of a disposed closure?

Tags: c#

I want invoke a list of functions. All functions return a bool. Depending on the bool, I want to break the loop invoking each function in the list of functions.

The functions requires a parameter which is an Entity Framework DbContext, instantiated in a "using block". There is a warning "Access to disposed closure"

```
using (var context = new DbContext())
{
   var fileDeletionProcedure = new List<Action>
   {
       () => _proc.deleteUsers(Id, context),
       () => _proc.deleteAccounts(Id, context),
       () => _proc.deleteMoney(Id, context)
   }
   foreach (var f in fileDeletionProcedure)
   {
       var exit = f.Invoke();
       if (exit)
       {
           break;
       }
   }
}
```

I want to do something like the code I provided, but `Invoke()` returns void, anyone have suggestions? Also, how would I deal with that warning regarding disposed closures?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the answer is to replace `Action` with `Func<bool>` or `Predicate` but this code looks strange. You get a warning because compiler doesn't know if you're going to execute these actions while still in `using` block. If you do it after, the context will be already disposed. If you don't - you can simply ignore this warning (put a comment with justification).

The proper way to do it is simply:

```
using (var context = new DbContext())
{
    if (_proc.deleteUsers(Id, context)
        || _proc.deleteAccounts(Id, context)
        || _proc.deleteMoney(Id, context))
    {
        return;
    }
}
```

`||` will exit as soon as possible so if `deleteUsers` returns `true` it will not execute `deleteAccounts` or `deleteMoney`.

But this still looks strange because nothing suggests that `deleteXXX` functions return `true` in case something wents wrong. You should rather reverse this logic and use `&&` instead of `||`

Answer (score 1):

This is just a *warning* and alerting you that you might be doing the wrong thing, obviously the actions will execute with in the context and it won't be disposed.

If this is a *Resharper* warning, you can disable this with a comment.

Also note, that actions don't return a result, you will need to use a `Func<bool>`:

```
// ReSharper disable AccessToDisposedClosure
var fileDeletionProcedure = new List<Func<bool>>
                            {
                               () => Something(db)
                            };
// ReSharper restore AccessToDisposedClosure


foreach (var f in fileDeletionProcedure)
{
   if (f.Invoke())
      break;
}
```